# Quantum Mechanics Spectral decomposition misunderstanding

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, matrix-elements

My notes state that the spectral decomposition formula is of the form:

$$ \hat{A} = \hat{A}\hat{1} = \sum{\hat{A} } |A_i\rangle\langle A_i | = \sum{A_i } |A_i\rangle\langle A_i |  $$

Now consider the Hamiltonian as
$$ \hat{H} = \begin{bmatrix}E&K\\K*&E\end{bmatrix}$$
It would be easy to show that the eigenvalues are $$E_+ =  E+|K|$$ and$$E_- =  E-|K| $$and the eigenstates are as follows:

$$ |+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{k}{|k|}\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix} $$

$$ |-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{-k}{|k|}\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix} $$

I was expected then to show that the unitary operator $$\hat{U}(t) = e ^{it\hat{H}/\hbar}$$ can be defined as follows:

$$\hat{U}(t)=e^{-i\hat{H}t/\hbar}=
e^{-iEt/\hbar}\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(|K|t/\hbar) & -i\frac{K}{|K|}\sin(|K|t/\hbar) \\
-i\frac{K^*}{|K|}\sin(|K|t/\hbar) & \cos(|K|t/\hbar) 
\end{pmatrix}$$

According to my notes the appropriate application of the spectral decomposition formula to do so is

$$ \hat{U}(t) = e ^{it{\hat{H}}/\hbar} =  e ^{it{E_+}/\hbar} |+\rangle\langle +|   + e ^{it{E_-}/\hbar} |-\rangle\langle -| $$

However if we recall the spectral decomposition formula as:
$$ \hat{U} = \hat{U}\hat{1} = \sum{\hat{U} } |U_i\rangle\langle U_i | = \sum{U_i } |U_i\rangle\langle U_i |  $$

My question therefore is why is it appropriate to use the $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ states when they are the eigenstates of the $\hat{H}$ operator and not the $\hat{U}(t)$ one?

Comment: Be extremely careful with the eigenstates you've written - they are either wrong or they depend on terminology not defined in this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question therefore is why is it appropriate to use the $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ states
> when they are the eigenstates of the $H$ operator and not the $U(t)$ one?

The eigenvectors $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ of $\hat{H}$
are also eigenvectors of $\hat{U}(t)$, because

$$\begin{align}
\hat{U}(t) |+\rangle
&=e^{it\hat{H}/\hbar} |+\rangle \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{it\hat{H}}{\hbar}\right)^n |+\rangle \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{itE_+}{\hbar}\right)^n |+\rangle \\
&=e^{itE_+/\hbar} |+\rangle
\end{align}$$

and similarly
$$\hat{U}(t) |-\rangle =e^{itE_-/\hbar} |-\rangle$$

This justifies the spectral decomposition of $\hat{U}(t)$:
$$\hat{U}(t) 
= e ^{it{E_+}/\hbar} |+\rangle\langle +|  
+ e ^{it{E_-}/\hbar} |-\rangle\langle -|$$